# Inequality with a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that  for $ R \gt 0, \quad \int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-R\sin\phi}\,d\phi \lt \frac{\pi}{2R}(1-e^{-R})$

It seems that the intermediate value theorem doesn't work here. A tried to use $x=R\cos\phi,\; y=R\sin\phi$, and thus $\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-R\sin\phi}\,d\phi = \int\limits_0^1\frac{e^{-y}\,dy}{x}$, but now both x and y depends on $\phi$ and I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin x >\frac {2x}  {\pi}$ for $0 <x<\frac {\pi} 2$. Hence the given integral is less than $\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R\frac {2\phi}  {\pi}} d\phi$. Now compute the integral explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! It was easy.